# How to get base64 image from AjaxFileUpload?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am trying to get the images put into an AjaxFileUpload as base64 strings.  Would I do this in OnUploadCompleteAll?

```
    protected void AjaxFileUpload1_UploadCompleteAll(object sender, AjaxFileUploadCompleteAllEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

In aspx:

```
<asp:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" runat="server" AllowedFileTypes="jpg,jpeg,png,gif" MaximumNumberOfFiles="5" OnUploadCompleteAll="AjaxFileUpload1_UploadCompleteAll"></asp:AjaxFileUpload>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `UploadCompleteAll` event fires when all files (in a multi-upload) have completed.

There is also another event that fires once for each file uploaded, called `UploadComplete`. You should handle that event.

```
// in ASPX page
<asp:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" 
                    runat="server"
                    AllowedFileTypes="jpg,jpeg,png,gif"
                    MaximumNumberOfFiles="5"
                    OnUploadCompleteAll="AjaxFileUpload1_UploadCompleteAll"
                    OnUploadComplete="AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete">
</asp:AjaxFileUpload>
```

And in code behind add something like this:

```
// in code-behind
protected void AjaxFileUpload1__OnUploadComplete(object sender, AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
{       
    if (e.ContentType.Contains("jpg") || file.ContentType.Contains("jpeg")
            || file.ContentType.Contains("png") || file.ContentType.Contains("gif"))
    {           
        // file.FileName contains the name of the file
        fileUploader.SaveAs(MapPath("path/where/you/want/to/save/file"));

        // once saved, you can further manipulate the file if you wish

    }
}
```